# Add listener remember previous click

Tags: jquery, listener

I have radio buttons:

```
<input class="transfer-item" type="radio" name="transfer" value="1">
<input class="transfer-item" type="radio" name="transfer" value="2">
<input class="transfer-item" type="radio" name="transfer" value="3">
```

And I need after click listen to iframe response. I have this code for it:

```
$('.transfer-item').each(function (key, item) {
    $(item).click(function (e) {
        var $main = $(item).closest('li');
        const $iframe = $main.find('iframe');
        if (!$iframe.attr('src')) {
            $iframe.attr('src', $iframe.data('src'));
            if (window.addEventListener) {
                window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
                if (event.data.message === 'pickerResult') {
                    var point = event.data.point;
                    console.log($main);
                    $main.find('.iframe-wrap').hide();
                    $main.find('.zip-code-select-text').text(point.address);
                    $main.find('.zip-code-select input:hidden').val(point.zip);
                    $main.find('.zip-code-select').show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

console.log return all clicks history:

[image]

How can I receive just current response from clicked radio button? I need some kind of cleaning listener.

**EDIT:**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input class="transfer-item" type="radio" name="transfer" value="1">
    <label>
      Transfer 1
      <div class="transfer-zip-code">
        <div class="iframe-wrap">
          <iframe data-src="https://b2c.cpost.cz/locations/?type=POST_OFFICE" allow="geolocation"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="zip-code-select">
          <input type="hidden" name="transfer_zip_code_1" value="">
          <span class="zip-code-select-text"></span>
          <a class="zip-code-select-change" href="#">Change</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="transfer-item" type="radio" name="transfer" value="2">
    <label>
      Transfer 2
      <div class="transfer-zip-code">
        <div class="iframe-wrap">
          <iframe data-src="https://b2c.cpost.cz/locations/?type=BALIKOVNY" allow="geolocation"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="zip-code-select">
          <input type="hidden" name="transfer_zip_code_2" value="">
          <span class="zip-code-select-text"></span>
          <a class="zip-code-select-change" href="#">Change</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: remove `$('.transfer-item').each(function (key, item) {` and then change code accordingly

Comment: The `item` in `$(item).closest('li');` isn't the item you think it is - it will have changed.  Use `$(this).closest(...`  See [javascript closures](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+closure)

Comment: $(this).closest(...) do same thing like $(item).closest(...). Just tried it.

Comment: @Alive to die - Anant Could you be more specify, please?

Comment: So everytime  a radio button is clicked, `window`  is registered with a new eventListener that is identical to the other eventListeners registered to `window`?

Comment: @zer00ne Yes, can they be separate?

Comment: Your comment in the answer below clarifies the problem (which was not clear before): *"First click on "Transfer 1" the console will print one, on the second (click "Transfer 2"), both"* - the issue, as noted by @zer00ne above, is that you are registering multiple `message` handlers.  You need to remove the previous one - in jquery (which you use partly) this would `$(window).off("message")` but will only work with jquery `.on`

Comment: `$('.transfer-item').each((k, item) => $(item).click` is already the same as `$(".transfer-item").click` - jquery *essentially* does the `each` internally.   Changing this has no impact on the code (changing `this` does...)

Comment: @freedomn-m I see the point. Could you give an example with .off('message')? I mean outside comment.

Comment: There's no further "example", it's just as it is in the comment above.  Example using click on a button:  `$("button").on("click", () => alert("click") );  $("button").off("click");`